# How does the Amazon nanny cam work behind NAT without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, security, port-forwarding, camera, cloud

I am trying to set up a home security camera system so I can view it on my phone from anywhere. It is a Alibi Hybrid DVR from supercircuits.com. I know the right way is to do port forwarding to set it up to view remotely, but I am not able to do that. The only internet I can reasonably get is a Jetpack from Verizon and all Verizon phones and jetpacks are given private IP addresses behind Verizon's network, thus unable to set up port forwarding. Yes, I can do it on my router the jetpack is hooked to and to the jetpack itself, but not on Verizon's network between the jetpack and the public internet.

Verizon does offer static public IP addresses, but only to business customers with a $500 fee, which I believe is absolutely absurd for something so basic as this for a private individual.

A friend of mine has a Amazon nanny cam they set up for their dogs. Something like this -- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PSCGZC6/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_Eht8Cb9BJ44QX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PSCGZC6) . They also have a jetpack for internet, but somehow they are able to view it remotely.

Clearly it must be possible to get a connection through without port forwarding, since my friend is not tech savvy enough to set up port forwarding. Does anyone know how I could set up my system or how the amazon camera works? Does it stream continuously to a cloud perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without port forwarding, typical home-router NAT prevents incoming connections, but it doesn't block outgoing ones.  So it's possible for the camera to initiate a connection to the service and get a connection started that way.  There's also other ways, many are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal).